# Add title and authors name in main and in the end of first page other info

Tags: presentations

I try to customize a presentation template. I try to create the first page. I would like to have in the footer something specific like the conference name and country.

The initial is this:

```
\documentclass{beamer} %
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}

\author{Elena Piper, Amina Shahid, April Fiorese}
\title{Evaluating the Change of Performance Metrics for Key ABS}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
```

What I tried:

```
\documentclass{beamer} %
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}

%\author{conference}
%\title{city}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\author{Elena Piper, Amina Shahid, April Fiorese}

\title{test}
\begin{comment}
:Title: Beamer arrows
:Tags: Remember picture, Beamer, Physics & chemistry, Overlays
:Use page: 3

With PGF/TikZ version 1.09 and later, it is possible to draw paths between nodes across
different pictures. This is a useful feature for presentations with the
Beamer package. In this example I've combined the new PGF/TikZ's overlay feature
with Beamer overlays. Download the PDF version to see the result.

**Note.** This only works with PDFTeX, and you have to run PDFTeX twice.

| Author: Kjell Magne Fauske

\end{comment}


% For every picture that defines or uses external nodes, you'll have to
% apply the 'remember picture' style. To avoid some typing, we'll apply
% the style to all pictures.
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

% By default all math in TikZ nodes are set in inline mode. Change this to
% displaystyle so that we don't get small fractions.
\everymath{\displaystyle}
```

I would like to keep the title and authors names as they are but change the text in the footer note in the first box will have the conference name and in the second have country name and in the third as is the timestamp.

How can I make it?